# High read error rate for a Seagate 14TB HDD, is this normal range?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, crystaldiskinfo, read

This is a new HDD, but it looks like the read error rate is too high.
It is higher than the threshold, but not sure if this a normal for a new HDD.
Should I request for a replacement?

[image: High read error rate CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: CDM marks the drive as "Good" and does not add any special indication to that SMART attribute. The raw value is also far too high to be of any real value. Therefore: **that SMART value should be ignored.** Also, learn how to take proper screenshots.

Comment: Normalized values go _down_. So the current value (80) is _better_ than the worst (64) or the threshold (44).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What's significant here is that we're dealing with a Seagate**. The following does not apply to other brands!

Seagate happens to one of the few manufacturers that explain what SMART means with regards to Seagate drives: http://t1.daumcdn.net/brunch/service/user/axm/file/zRYOdwPu3OMoKYmBOby1fEEQEbU.pdf

```
3.1 Attribute ID 1: Raw Error Rate
Normalized Raw Error Rate = 10 * log10(NumberOfSectorsTransferredToOrFromHost * 512 * 8 /
(Number of sectors requiring retries))
Where the factor of 512*8 is to convert from sectors to bits. The attribute value is only
computed when the number of bits in the "transferred bits" count is in the range 1010 to 1012
.
The counts are cleared when Number Of Bits Transferred To Or From Host > 1012.
“Number of sectors requiring retries” does not count free retry or hidden retry.
Normalized Raw Error Rate is evaluated to a number between 1 and 166.
Raw Usage
Raw [3 – 0] = Number of sector reads
Raw [6 - 4] = Number of read errors.
```

So, The raw value of the SMART attribute occupies 48 bits. Seagate’s Seek Error Rate attribute consists of two parts — a 16-bit count of seek errors in the uppermost 4 nibbles, and a 32-bit count of seeks in the lowermost 8 nibbles.

So 0x000005B7B605 -> 0000-05B7B605 => no read errors, 95925765 reads.

If you want you can use this [online form](https://www.disktuna.com/seagate-raw-smart-attributes-to-error-convertertest/) that does the calculation for you, for attributes:

```
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate
7 Seek_Error_Rate
```